# Emmet expand only HTML tags

Tags: filetype-html, plugin-emmet-vim

Hi I'm trying to make emmet expand only Html tags. For example `div<c-y>,` should be expanded to

```
<div></div>
```

But `abc<c-y>,` should not be expanded. By default emmet expands every word, I wonder if there's a setting to expand only html tags. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] sergio :) have you consulted with the plugin maintainers/its documentation?

Comment: Yes, they suggested to use `:EmmetInstall` but that didn't help: https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/issues/480